# how to write a code(c#) to make users cannot enter wrong data type?

Tags: c#, button, textbox

I want to write code using C# which is used for users entering data in a textbox but they shouldn't enter integers. They have to enter letters not numbers or operations etc. For example when they enter "asss12", the program shows up a dialog windows telling "you enter wrong type". it has to control the data one by one.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    int result;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < textBox1.Text.Length; i++)
    {
        if (int.TryParse(textBox1.Text.Substring(i, 1), out result))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("yanlış girdiniz");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("thank you");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into Regular Expressions?

Comment: this is just basic data validation

Comment: Have you put any effort in this so far?

Comment: `bool invalid=text.Any(Char.IsDigit)`

Comment: Do you want to NOT allow them to even type numbers or do you want to validate after they enter things?

Comment: I have a strong suspicion that this is going about something the wrong way entirely.  This wouldn't by any chance be a name input, would it?  What are you *actually* validating about the string?

Answer (score 1):

For Windows Forms:

1. Drop a MaskedTextBox onto your form.
2. Change its [`Mask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to something like `LLLLLL` (repeat `L` once for each desired character).

Similar controls are available for WPF.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the use of Regex, here is the correct Regex expression to check against

```
 ([a-zA-Z\s])+
```